# How to Increase model accuracy when using classification algorithm for text classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning, neural-network, nlp

I am using SVM classification algorithm to classify the articles but I am confused, why the accuracy of model is getting decreased as the number of samples increases. below are the accuracy stats that I captured with different C values that's hyper parameter.

can anyone help me to increase further accuracy with increased number of samples?

Task that is being performed:

> classify the news articles on various categories like sports,politics,entertainment etc.

Sample code >>

```
# dummy data (in real problem this is a big list)
glbl_list = [['samples_id','sample_prediction','sample_article'],['samples_id','sample_prediction','sample_article']]

# shuffling the whole data
order = [j for j in range(len(glbl_list))]
random.shuffle(glbl_list)
glbl_list = [glbl_list[i] for i in order]

# creating a dataframe out of above list
Corpus = pd.DataFrame(glbl_list, columns = ['id', 'label', 'text'])

# perform various data cleaning task like stopwords,punc. marks removal etc

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
x = tfidf.fit_transform(Corpus['text'].values)

encoder = LabelEncoder() 
y = encoder.fit_transform(Corpus['label'])

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1)

clf = svm.SVC(C=1, kernel='linear')
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)

print("Accuracy: {}".format(clf.score(x_train, y_train)))
print("Accuracy: {}".format(clf.score(x_test, y_test)))
```

> accuracy captured(at Best possible C values):
> samples:(500)
> when C = 1
> Train_Accuracy: 0.9933333333333333
> Test_Accuracy: 0.98
>
> samples:(1000)
> when C = 2.5
> Train_Accuracy: 0.9833333333333333
> Test_Accuracy: 0.9
>
> samples:(5000)
> when C = 1
> Train_Accuracy: 0.8533333333333334
> Test_Accuracy: 0.81
>
> samples:(8000)
> when C = 1
> Train_Accuracy: 0.8983333333333333
> Test_Accuracy: 0.8475
>
> samples:(10000)
> when C = 1
> Train_Accuracy: 0.7488888888888889
> Test_Accuracy: 0.69
>
> samples:(12000)
> when C = 0.6
> Train_Accuracy: 0.6548148148148148
> Test_Accuracy: 0.6333333333333333

Comment: How are the "number of samples" incorporated into this? Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). My first guess: If samples are being taken from a contiguous array: `x` and `y` could be biased toward a small number of classes. For example: `1000` samples might be trained/tested on only two types of news articles, meaning the classification accuracy could appear artificially high.

Comment: Hi Alex,
yeah I had a thought of that too but i have already covered that part by shuffling the entire articles with their predictions and then splitting it in between test and training data.
below is the sample code :
# shuffling the data
order = [j for j in range(len(glbl_list))]
random.shuffle(glbl_list)
glbl_list = [glbl_list[i] for i in order]

where this glbl_list = [['news article', 'predictions'],['news article', 'prediction']]

1000 samples contains around 4-5 unique category and this increases as the number samples increases.

Comment: Please edit your question, code in the comments is unreadable.

Comment: But yes, this still sounds odd. If you edit the question with a reproducible example it may be reopened.

Comment: edited the question.. let me know for more information.